# ASP.NET page life cycle explanation

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I was asked to explain the ASP.NET page life cycle in an interview some time back. I did explain it to him, but he was not satisfied with my answer. Could someone explain the life cycle to me please?

Answer (score 15):

There are 10 events in ASP.NET page life cycle, and the sequence is:

1. Init
2. Load view state
3. Post back data
4. Load
5. Validate
6. Events
7. Pre-render
8. Save view state
9. Render
10. Unload

Below is a pictorial view of ASP.NET Page life cycle with what kind of code is expected in that event. I suggest you read [this article I wrote on the ASP.NET Page life cycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle), which explains each of the 10 events in detail and when to use them.

[image: ASP.NET life cycle]

Image source: my own article at https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/Asp-Net-application-and-page-life-cycle/ from 19 April 2010

Comment: Nice visual.  I can show this to management to help them understand what I'm trying to explain about multiple trips to the database due to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

This acronym might help you to remember the ASP.NET life cycle stages which I wrote about in the below blog post.

> > **R-SIL-VP-RU**
>
> 1. Request
> 2. Start
> 3. Initialization
> 4. Load
> 5. Validation
> 6. Post back handling
> 7. Rendering
> 8. Unload

From my blog: [Understand ASP.NET Page life cycle and remember stages in easy way](http://www.iminfo.in/post/asp-net-page-life-cycle-stages-remember-it-in-easy-way)

 18 May 2014

Comment: It's important to provide explicit disclosure of any affiliation to avoid your posts being flagged as spam. I noticed all of your answers on SO were posted with a link to the same blog (in fact, the entire content of each answer relies heavily on said link), where each specific link was to a specific blog article posted *less than a single day* before each of your respective answers were posted.

Comment: Also, this acronym is not at all easy to commit to memory. Perhaps a mnemonic like "RSVP, Russia" for "**R**épondez **S**'**il** **V**ou **P**laît, **Ru**ssia" would be easier?

Answer (score -3):

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim str As String

    Protected Sub Page_Disposed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Disposed

        str += "PAGE DISPOSED" & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Error(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Error
        str += "PAGE ERROR " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        str += "PAGE INIT " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_InitComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.InitComplete
        str += "INIT Complte " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        str += "PAGE LOAD " & "<br />"

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
        str += "PAGE LOAD Complete " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        str = ""
        str += "PAGE PRE INIT" & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreLoad(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
        str += "PAGE PRE LOAD " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        str += "PAGE PRE RENDER " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_PreRenderComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
        str += "PAGE PRE RENDER COMPLETE " & "<br />"
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_SaveStateComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SaveStateComplete
        str += "PAGE SAVE STATE COMPLTE  " & "<br />"
        lbl.Text = str
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Unload(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
        'Response.Write("PAGE UN LOAD\n")
    End Sub
End Class
```