# what event fires before any other event in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, events

I want to know which event is firing before any other event else? which event fires before Button Click or any other control else. if there is not, how can I implement some event myself?. I also want it to work with UpdatePanel.
the Page_PreRender fires after other events... which one fires before them?
thanks in advance.

Comment: read about events and their order here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.90).aspx#lifecycle_events

Comment: I need to do it for all postback events. raise it before them...

Answer (score 0):

There are several events in the `Page` lifecycle that occur before `PreRender`. Notably: `Init`, `Load`, and Postback event handlers.

Can you be more specific about what you want to do? I would suggest using `Page_Load` to do something on every load. This will allow you to prepare the data for your page to render.

The first place you can initialize data is either in a base class or in the `Page`'s constructor. Here is one pattern to use in your `Page`, for example (c#):

```
public class MemberInfo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // member variables
    private string memberId;

    // UI members defined in .aspx,.ascx,etc. file
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox checkboxPremiumMember;

    // default constructor
    public MemberInfo()
    {
         // step 1: initialize data
         memberId = null;
    }
    // event handlers
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // step 2: initialize page controls and event handlers
        checkboxPremiumMember.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // step 3: load data, populate controls, databinding stuff..
        memberId = Request.QueryString["memberId"];
        bool authenticated = AuthenticateMemberId(memberId);
        if (authenticated)
        {
             checkboxPremiumMember.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
             Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
        }
    }

    // step 4: postback event handlers (if any)
    protected void checkboxPremiumMember_OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // step 5: PreRender
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    // step 6: Render
    protected void Page_Render(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

There are a few other events too, like `LoadViewState` and `SaveViewState`, and others. You will want to understand the ASP.NET Page Lifecycle. See a related answer here:
[ASP.NET page life cycle explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457297/best-way-to-explain-asp-net-page-life-cycle)

or just google "asp.net page lifecycle"