# Earliest opportunity to catch a page view

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageviews, flooding

I have a function I wish to be called on every page view, at the earliest possible opportunity.  The code gets the users IP address, an increments a counter by 1 in a database.

This code is a basic flood limiter.  If more than `x` requests are made in interval `i` then it temporarially bans that IP address.  This is why the check needs to be as early as possible and on every page.

**Calling in MasterPages Page_Init**

This seems to work OK, however sometimes the counter increments by more than 1 (I assume if there's a URL re-write or redirect).

**Calling in Global.asax on Session_Start**

It seems to add `~30` to the counter on each page view.

What's the best way to catch a page view at the earliest possible opportunity, preferably without needing to change every single page on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Global.asax, you can hook to [HttpApplication.BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx), which is :

> the first event in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution when ASP.NET
>   responds to a request

This will fire for each request (for images, css, javascript, and so on). If you want to filter on pages only, you could write a HttpModule, that only increment your counter according to request extension.

Comment: If I add this into my global.asax file, one page view seems to fire this event ~30-50 times.

Comment: This is because for each page there are numerous ressources, like images, javascript, css files, etc

Answer (score 1):

`Page_Init` is [the earliest event you can subscribe to in WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457297/best-way-to-explain-asp-net-page-life-cycle), so that is the way to go.

> sometimes the counter increments by more than 1 (I assume if there's a URL re-write or redirect).

How is that a problem? A redirect is followed by another request, so it *is* another request. If you want to exclude those, you'll have to check in the latest event (`Page_Unload` in the case of WebForms) whether the response will perform a redirect and if so, subtract one from the counter, if that is the desired result.

Alternatively see [Best way to implement request throttling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc) if you don't want to reinvent the wheel.

As per @mathieu's answer, you can swap `Page_Init` with [`HttpApplication.BeginRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) and `Page_Unload` with [`HttpApplication.EndRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.endrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) and perform the same logic, to make it independent of WebForms. You can hook up these events in Global.asax.