# Server looking for vb source file - Why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I deployed an update to my asp.net website. It was one aspx file and all the files in bin. (After compiling the website.) When I run the website it says that the vb file (for the file I updated) doesn't exist, when I try to access the aspx file. Why is it even looking at the vb file? Shouldn't it be using the compiled stuff in the bin?

Here's the error I get....

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The file '/Member/xxxxxxxx.aspx.vb' does not exist.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Layouts/SingleColumnFormed.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
Line 2:    CodeFile="xxxxxxxx.aspx.vb" Inherits="Member_xxxxxxx" Title="Self Study" %>
Line 3:  

Source File: /Member/xxxxxxxx.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: please post the full error. Remember that ASPX provides a definition for a page class that at run time is generated from the markup and is derived from the classes you define. It's more complex than what you're saying. Start reading this qa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457297/best-way-to-explain-asp-net-page-life-cycle

Comment: Is there an exception? If there is, it's critical that you tell us what the exception is.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your file, `/Member/xxxxxxxxx.aspx`. In the `@ Page` directive, you'll see that it specifies the CodeFile is `xxxxxxxxx.aspx.vb`. If you don't need the codefile, you can delete that attribute from the using directive. Otherwise make sure the file exists on the server in the Member folder.

Comment: All my aspx pages have similar references and those pages are working fine. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a change to a page on the server, IIS/.NET will attempt to re-compile the page, including its code behind, on the first usage. Since you have already compiled the rest of the site, IIS/.NET will do everything it can to minimize the impact on the newly compiled pages. You will have an additional DLL for the updated page only.

This is normal and expected behavior.