# Update table with TextBox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update

I have some textboxes that are populated with customer info from a database (name, address) on page load. I want users to be able to simply change this and click a button to update their personal information.

I have the following code that runs on button click:

```
con.Open();
string query = "UPDATE CustomerInfo SET FirstName=@FirstName, LastName=@LastName, Address=@Address, PostalCode=@PostalCode, PostalName=@PostalName WHERE UserName=@UserName";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtLastName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddress.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPostalCode.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPostalName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

This does not work. If I change the textbox to something different and click the button, nothing happens. The table is not updated with the new values, and I get no error messages. However, if I change the Parameter values from for example `txtFirstName.Text` to `"Bob"`, it successfully updates the FirstName column in my table to Bob.

Not sure what I'm missing, but for some reason using textbox.Text as value doesn't work.

Comment: Are you resetting the textbox value some where in the page_load/init before a button click?

Comment: As @Murali says this is almost certainly an issue with setting the text of those textboxs somewhere else in the page lifecycle. I highly recommend reading up on the [page lifecycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457297/asp-net-page-life-cycle-explanation) and where event handlers factor into it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm setting the text with some information from a database on page_load. I assumed textbox.Text would be automaticly updated when I changed the textbox content. I was hoping there would be an easy way to deal with this, but I guess I'll take a look at page lifecycle. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes parameter value as a second parameter, not [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You are mixing it with [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtFirstName.Text;
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

**EDIT**: Ok, that's not the point as you said (And I can't delete my answer because of 5 answer delete limit). I really doubt that your textbox values change in your page life-cycle. By the way, where did you defined these code? Be sure that your textbox values keep their values since these codes were execute.

Comment: If you read OP specifically `However, if I change the Parameter values from for example txtFirstName.Text to "Bob", it successfully updates the FirstName column in my table to Bob`. Looks like current code has problem with the text box values

Comment: @Murali You are right. But I can't delete this answer because I had 5 delete answer limit for today. You can downvote it.