# ASP.NET page_load events

Tags: asp.net, events

Imagine I have one page_load event in aspx page and same page_load event in the code behind. Which of them will run first? Or both of them will run simultaneously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET page life cycle explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457297/asp-net-page-life-cycle-explanation)

Answer (score 0):

If that works, it should NOT. Why would you mix code in the aspx and in the code behind? Anyway, just test it (add a Response.WriteLine to each event and check what happens).