# how many times page_init function fires if many diffrent users sends multiple request to server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, page-init

In an exam I have to find out anwser of this question about asp.net.

the question is, if we have a variable named 'pagehits', and we increment this var by 1 in **both** *page_init and page_load* functions. After making 20 requests from 20 diffrent clients, what will be the final value of 'pagehits'? I know that page_init fires only once, but if 20 **diffrent** users send the request, how many times would that fires? So we know that in this senario Page_Load function fires 20 times; does page_init fire only one time or it fires for all 20 clients?

and is the answer *pagehits=21* correct or 40?

'pagehits' default value is zero.

thank you very much

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: unfortunately I have no access to any useful device now. and it was urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does page_init fire only one time or it fires for all 20 clients?

It fires for all 20 clients. The only difference between `Init` and `Load` is *when* it fires: `Init` comes first, `Load` happens later. For details, see the following question:

- [ASP.NET page life cycle explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8457297/87698)

Note that, if the *same* client makes *another* request, both `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` fire again, so this technique is not suitable for counting "unique visitors".

> and is the answer pagehits=21 correct or 40?

If `pagehits` is static, it will be 40. If `pagehits` isn't, each request has its own instance of the variable, rendering the question moot. Do note, though, that the value of static variables will be lost when the application pool recycles. If that value is important to you, you need to *persist* it somewhere, for example, in a database or a file.